# Parsing XML into multiple tables using Hive XML SerDe

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive, xml-parsing

I have a bunch of structured XML files that I want to insert into Hive. The structure looks somewhat like this:

```
<Object>
    <property0>propertyValue</property0>
    <FirstNestedObjects>
        <FirstNestedObject>
            <property1>propertyValue</property1>
        </FirstNestedObject>
    </FirstNestedObjects>

    <SecondNestedObjects>
        <SecondNestedObject>
            <property2>propertyValue</property2>
        </SecondNestedObject>
    </SecondNestedObjects>
</Object>
```

I wish to parse this XML into 3 tables: **Objects**, **FirstNestedObjects**, **SecondNestedObjects**

The columns for each of these tables would be the properties inside the objects. I wish to do this so I can do analytics on aggregated FirstNestedObjects and SecondNestedObjects.

I've tried looking at their documentation located here: https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources however it shows only how to parse the information into a single table.

Any idea on how I should approach this problem?

Comment: I am not sure why you need to create separate tables to aggregate values. if you must, the simple way would be to write 3 separate create table statements to create 3 separate tables and extract the particular xpath entry.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution might be to create a partitioned table with 3 partitions. In your query you can write the data to the required partition. So in the end you would have 3 separate directories on which you can create tables to individually query them.